# Read NFC tag present before app launch

Tags: android, nfc

I'm trying to read NFC tag using NfcAdapter (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html )

It is working fine, but if the tag was already present before I start my application, it is not detected.

Is it possible to read it without having to put it away and rescan it ?

I tried with other apps (TagInfo, NFC Tools, ...) and all seem to have the same problem. Is it a limitation ?

But when I'm installing the app the first time, the tag is detected. I guess the first time the app ask for NFC access permission or something like this...